# How to make these jquery pop ups fall back to css when javascript disabled

Tags: jquery, css, popup

I have this pop up menu that I plan to use on a map. I want this to fall back to css hover when Java script is disabled. I have tried with sibling selectors and can't get it to work.

here is the fiddle:

[The fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AJBweb1986/GQzEn/1/)

Comment: You could try adding/removing classes with Javascript, so you can differentiate the behavior.

Comment: How would I do this?, I am quite a newbie when it comes to jquery and javascript.

Comment: you could check my answer? :)
Both responding at the same time again @bažmegakapa. :)

Comment: Could edit the fiddle just to give me an Idea?

Comment: @AshleyBriscoe The [jQuery manual](http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/class-attribute/) is a good place to start. Also, if you are really an absolute beginner, completing some tutorials would serve you better. We could do it for you, but I'm not sure you would learn a lot from that.

Comment: I tend to learn backwards if I see it working I can dissect it and see how it works. I am okay with simple stuff

Comment: I added a JSFidle to my answer. The difference between sebastianForsberg answer and mine is the amount of code to write. You only need to add one line of text to your JS and one line of text to your hover. But it's okay if you like to write a lot of code without being able to reuse it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this for all locations:

```
#location1:hover .pop-up{
   display:block;
   opacity:1;            
}
```

add transitions for the fade-in/out effect

Answer (score 1):

You can let your javascript/jQuery remove the class hoverCSS from your map on document ready

Like this:

```
$("#Map").removeClass("hoverCSS");
//adding the hoverJS class or just toggle the hover JS
$("#Map").addClass("hoverJS");
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GQzEn/7/): this should give you a small idea to do it in JS not 100% and without the css hover.